# Go green with environment-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

There are three overlapping environment-related tags: [environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment), [work-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/work-environment), and [physical-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/physical-environment), none of which are defined, plus [desktop-environments](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-environments), which does not overlap.  I did some cleanup in the [environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment) tag and the usages of the three tags now look mainly like this:

[environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment):

- system-related interaction (infrastructure rather than applications/desktop-environment)
- development environment

[work-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/work-environment):

- virtual environment
- isolated software installation
- workflow and software tools
- computer setup
- surrounding physical environment related to computer setup

[physical-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/physical-environment):

- computer setup
- surrounding physical environment related to computer setup
- environmental factors affecting hardware performance

These might logically be grouped like this:

- Virtual environment: use the numerous existing tags relating to this
- Workflow and software tools: Use the existing application tags or create as needed

New (or renamed from [environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment)) tag: [operating-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/operating-environment) or [computing-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computing-environment):

- system-related interaction
- development environment
- isolated software installation

[work-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)

- computer setup
- surrounding physical environment related to the user or computer setup

[physical-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/physical-environment)

- environmental factors affecting hardware performance (temperature, power, wireless transmission obstacles, weather, etc.)

Recommendation: Rename the [environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment) tag or delete it and create a new system-related one.  Create definitions for the three tags.  Retag as needed to move questions to the appropriate tag.  Suggestions for terminology or wiki excerpt wording are welcomed.

Comment: Don't forget about [tag:environment-variables]

Comment: @KevinPanko - Yeah, there are other environment-related tags.  These three suffer from overlap, which isn't a problem for the other ones.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that when I see [tag:environment] it makes me think of [tag:environment-variables] first.

Comment: @KevinPanko - This question is also a Rorschach test.  You passed.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I didn't think you *could* "fail" a Rorschach test.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I do all the time.  They just scratch their heads and wonder what species provided the result.

Comment: If the solution to a problem is removing everything between the keyboard and the chair, should the question be retagged as `work-environment` or `physical-environment`?

Comment: @Jeeped - You mean remove the "meat-sack"?  Sounds like something Mokubai would write (see answer and comments on this question: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8870/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-questions-involving-human-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

This one is completed.  Despite a wiki excerpt being added saying [environment] is deprecated, don't use it, someone already reused it.  This tag needs to be deleted, or to use an Al Gore phrase, put in a lockbox.

Comment: Shouldn't this happen "Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day." Source: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Comment: The cleanup might have missed the cutoff time.

Comment: True... Well, you just have to do border police and wait :(